# File not attached to an email with applescript

Tags: applescript

My problem is that although the code seem to work fine, the mail is sent but without the file attached.
The console does not show any error.
Where´s the problem?. (I´m new with AppleScript)
This is my code. Thanks.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set carpetaDelArchivo to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:Alberto:Documents:scripts:"
    set archivoAdjunto to the (first file in carpetaDelArchivo)
end tell

--rellenar los datos del correo (destinatario, asunto, etc)
set destinatario to "xxx@icloud.com"
set enviadoPor to "yyy@hotmail.com"
set asunto to "Prueba con applescript"
set contenido to "Bla bla bla..... " & return & return & "Esto es una prueba"

--abrir aplicación de correo
tell application "Mail"

--crear el correo
set nuevoMensaje to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:asunto, content:contenido, sender:enviadoPor}
log "mensaje creado"

    tell nuevoMensaje

        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:destinatario}
        tell content of nuevoMensaje
            try
                make new attachment with properties {file name:archivoAdjunto as alias} at after last paragraph
                log "archivo adjuntado"

            on error errores
                log errores

            end try
        end tell
     end tell

--message mensaje
send nuevoMensaje

log "mensaje enviado"

end tell
```

Comment: When I switched from Snow Leopard to ElCapitain, I solved similar issue by just adding a "delay 1" instruction between the "make new attachment..." and the "Send". ..and it works

Comment: Problem solved @pbell. Thanks.